# Open to explode as a result

Tags: jquery

```
$.ajax({
    type    : 'GET',
    dataType: 'html',
    url     : 'data.php',
    data    : dataString,
    success : function(callback){           
        $('.opendiv').html(callback);
        $('.opendiv').explode(callback); // ???


    },
    error   : function(error){
        alert(error);
    }           
});
```

I want to open with the outcome of Ajax ui effect explode. my english is not good.sorry

Comment: The argument to `.explode()` is supposed to be the number of pieces. You're giving it HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument to `explode()` should be the number of pieces, which should be a perfect square. Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type    : 'GET',
    dataType: 'html',
    url     : 'data.php',
    data    : dataString,
    success : function(callback){           
        $('.opendiv').html(callback).toggle("explode");
    },
    error   : function(error){
        alert(error);
    }           
});
```

Comment: Does it work without `explode()`? Are you getting any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: TypeError: $(...).html(...).explode is not a function
jquery-1.9.1.js
Line 90

Comment: Sounds like you forgot to load jquery-ui.js.

Comment: /*! jQuery UI - v1.10.0 - 2013-02-14  loaded...  because .show ('explode') working...

Comment: `explode` isn't a method, it's an animation effect. Try my updated code.